# window, $, google not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, angular-universal

I am using Angular CLI + Universal and I have problems with Browser variables like window, $ Jquery and google, etc..

I tried to solve with webpack like this:

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        window: undefined,
        document: undefined,
        location: JSON.stringify({
            protocol: 'https',
            host: 'localhost',
        })
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    })

]
```

I have in my component for example following code:

```
 window.location.reload()
```

which will not work. 
Also, I have within my node_modules which use window variable.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those variables are not available on server side. If you want to use them in your code, you need to check if the current context is browser or server:

```
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) { ... }

ngOnInit() {
  if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
     // Client only code.
     ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, with this technique, you can use those conditionaly only in browser, where they are available.

Comment: Ok, now I am getting following error in backend Discarding entity body for GET requests

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do GET request with some payload - that is not allowed.

Comment: Ok my routing looks like const routes:Routes = [
  { path: ' ', component: SearchComponent }
 

] ; but I don't understand what I need to do

Comment: The problem could be that I am using absolute path for my request

Comment: Absolute path should be ok, that error/warning is not about angular routing, but about making GET request with payload (like when you do with POST request), so check where you call `http.get` in your code. It is definitely not connected to this issue with `window`, etc...

Comment: Ok, my node.js app.js looks like this app.get('*.*', express.static(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});  Should I need call http request on client side http.get  or can I change app.js get to post?

Comment: You should open a new question for this, as it is really not connected to the missing `window` on server side. Btw problem is in making the get request, not in your node server. You need to find the place that causes the problem first and then decide if you need POST request or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a misunderstanding on how `new webpack.ProvidePlugin` works. What it does is simply import those items for you for packed files, not expose them as variables that you can access from the browser's console at will

if you wish to access these externally, I would suggest doing this in your `application.js` or whatever your entry file is

```
import jquery from 'jquery'

window.$ = jquery
window.jquery = jquery
window.jQuery = jquery
```

doing this should allow you to access jquery on the browser's console.
as for window being inaccessible from within your components, perhaps the code below has something to do with it

```
window: undefined,
document: undefined,
```